# Can a Green Card holder re-enter the country with an expired passport?

Tags: usa, greencard, passport

My passport expired and I have to leave the country in a month to attend a wedding abroad.

I am a Green Card Holder, can I leave and re-enter the country just presenting the Green Card or is the Passport a mandatory requirement?

Comment: The question was answered on this Travel.StackExchange webpage: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114487/can-a-us-permanent-resident-re-enter-the-us-with-an-expired-peruvian-passport

Comment: Thanks @David .

Comment: US permanent residents do not need any passport to enter the US.  The green card is sufficient by itself.  But how are you going to enter your destination country if your passport is expired?

Comment: Good point..!  .

Comment: Perhaps it's the country of origin and they have to let the OP in.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my country of origin.. :(